# When trying to get the Flutter packages for flutter-folio repository, I face a timeout for auto_size_text.git

Tags: flutter, git, github, pubspec, pubspec.yaml

I am trying to give a go with Flutter Folio sample project by cloning it and running it in the iOS simulator locally. Here's what I did and the issue I faced with.

First I cloned the repository, and then tried to update the packages.

```
git clone https://github.com/gskinnerTeam/flutter-folio.git
cd flutter-folio
flutter packages get
```

Usually this works for me and I get to then open up VSCode, examine the code, and then run the code in the simulator. However at the `flutter packages get` command I faced the following issue:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter-folio...
Resolving dependencies... (12.1s)
Git error. Command: `git clone --mirror git://github.com/gskinnerTeam/auto_size_text.git /Users/sydmk/.pub-cache/git/cache/auto_size_text-ee02f76d882179635fdb79a3e4ed36d6513147b7`
stdout: 
stderr: Cloning into bare repository '/Users/sydmk/.pub-cache/git/cache/auto_size_text-ee02f76d882179635fdb79a3e4ed36d6513147b7'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 20.248.137.48]: errno=Operation timed out

exit code: 128
pub get failed
command: "/GitCodeTools/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart __deprecated_pub --color --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "/GitCodeTools/flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "/Users/sydmk/.pub-cache",
}
exit code: 69
```

Since this looks like a Timeout, I went ahead and checked in the pubspec.yaml and there was the auto_size_text repository. Here's an extract of what I have:

```
name: flutter_folio
description: Create and share beautiful Scrapbooks using Photos, Text and Stickers!
publish_to: "none"
version: 1.2.3

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  anchored_popups: ^0.1.0
  animate_do: ^2.0.0
  auto_size_text:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/gskinnerTeam/auto_size_text.git
      ref: 8800276218b053265ffc796a24e84820bebaaeac
  bitsdojo_window: ^0.1.0+1
  cached_network_image: ^3.0.0
  cloudinary_public: ^0.8.0
  context_menus: ^0.1.0+5
  darq: ^1.0.0-dev.3
  desktop_window: ^0.4.0
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.0
  email_validator: ^2.0.1
  enum_to_string: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.1
  flutter_lorem: ^2.0.0
```

So I tried to clone auto_size_text.git myself, and that seemed to work fine:

```
git clone https://github.com/gskinnerTeam/auto_size_text.git 
Cloning into 'auto_size_text'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 663, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (168/168), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (38/38), done.
remote: Total 663 (delta 136), reused 130 (delta 130), pack-reused 495
Receiving objects: 100% (663/663), 5.93 MiB | 5.36 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (338/338), done.
```

Just to test, I tried changing `git://github.com/gskinnerTeam/auto_size_text.git` to `https://github.com/gskinnerTeam/auto_size_text.git` in the pubspec.yaml. And that got over the error.

Now my question is if I did the right thing here?

Also next I'm stuck at the below error

```
    And because test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.18 <1.16.0-nullsafety.19 depends on test_api 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 and every version of flutter_test from
      sdk depends on test_api 0.4.16, one of freezed ^0.14.0-nullsafety.1 or flutter_launcher_icons >=0.9.0 <0.12.0 or test any or flutter_test from
      sdk must be false.
    And because flutter_folio depends on both test any and flutter_test from sdk, freezed ^0.14.0-nullsafety.1 is incompatible with
      flutter_launcher_icons >=0.9.0 <0.12.0.
    So, because flutter_folio depends on both freezed ^0.14.1 and flutter_launcher_icons ^0.9.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed
command: "/GitCodeTools/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart __deprecated_pub --color --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "/GitCodeTools/flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "/Users/sydmk/.pub-cache",
}
exit code: 1
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Isn't auto_size_text in the pub?

Comment: I'm really new to this, can you explain a bit, where I should look for it pls?